# Parser converts String to Any type

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I have the following simple parser (in reality its a bit more complicated, but this trivial example illustrates the problem just the same).

I have the first parser matching `name`, a `String` which for some reason gets converted to type `Any` instead. Also, the second 2 lists are optional, so they could be present or they couldn't. However in my domain object their respective sets will be empty in case they're not.

I can't seem to get my head around the first issue. For some reason when I remove the first `<~` the name becomes a `String` again, and the only remaining errors are the ones with the optional lists, which I presume I could go around in some way by matching the `Option` instance, although I am going to have quite a number of these optional lists, I don't want all permutations of them, with Some and None.

What is the best approach for this?

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

case class Test(name: String, extensions : Set[String] = Set[String](), 
                objects : Set[String] = Set[String]())

object TestParser extends RegexParsers {
  def test = "((:name" ~> name <~ ")" ~ (extensions_def?) ~ (objects_def?) <~ ")" ^^ {
      case name ~ extensions_def ~ objects_def =>
        Test(name, extensions_def, objects_def)
    }

  def name : Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*""".r

  def extensions_def = "(:extensions" ~> (extensions_key+) <~ ")"
  def extensions_key = ":funcs" | ":literals" | ":numbers"

  def objects_def = "(:objects" ~> (name+) <~ ")"

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val s = "(test hello (:extensions :funcs :numbers) (:objects obj1 obj2 obj3))"

    val res = parseAll(test, s)
    res match {
      case Success(r, n) => println(r)
      case Failure(msg, n) => println(msg)
      case Error(msg, n) => println(msg)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group `"(:name" ~> name <~ ")"` inside parenthesis (or you could define `name_def` like you did for `extensions_def` and `objects_def`). As for matching the `None/Some` permutations, it's probably easier to just match on the option and define a `optionListToSet` method, as I did below :

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

case class Test(name: String, extensions : Set[String] = Set[String](), 
  objects : Set[String] = Set[String]())

object TestParser extends RegexParsers {
  def test = "(" ~> ("(:name" ~> name <~ ")") ~ (extensions_def?) ~ (objects_def?) <~ ")" ^^ {
    case name ~ extensions_def ~ objects_def =>
      Test(name, optionListToSet(extensions_def), optionListToSet(objects_def))
  }

  def optionListToSet[A](o:Option[List[A]]) = o.map(_.toSet).getOrElse(Set[A]())

  def name : Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*""".r

  def extensions_def = "(:extensions" ~> (extensions_key+) <~ ")"
  def extensions_key = ":funcs" | ":literals" | ":numbers"

  def objects_def = "(:objects" ~> (name+) <~ ")"

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val s1 = "((:name test) (:extensions :funcs :numbers) (:objects obj1 obj2 obj3))"
    val res1 = parseAll(test, s1)
    res1 match {
      case Success(r, n) => println(r)
      case Failure(msg, n) => println(msg)
      case Error(msg, n) => println(msg)
    }

    val s2 = "((:name test) (:objects obj1 obj2 obj3))"
    val res2 = parseAll(test, s2)
    res2 match {
      case Success(r, n) => println(r)
      case Failure(msg, n) => println(msg)
      case Error(msg, n) => println(msg)
    }
  }
}
```

`Output :`

`Test(test,Set(:funcs, :numbers),Set(obj1, obj2, obj3))`

`Test(test,Set(),Set(obj1, obj2, obj3))`

Comment: Thanks for your help. So, why did we need to put the `<~` inside parenthesis?